# How to get transactionManager reference in Spring Programmatic transaction

Tags: spring, transactions, jms

I want to use spring programmatic transaction in JMS application that receive a message from queue. At the same time, I want to include the queue in transactional scope.

Using Spring DefaultMessageListnereContainer and injecting transaction manager in it. However, not sure how will I get the reference of this transaction to programmatically commit or rollback?

---

I read and understand "processing messages within transactions" here 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-tx-participation

My 2 requirements are - 
1) XA transactions hence injecting JtaTransactionManager, 
2) Use programmatic transactions - here I need help how to get reference to the transaction started by spring in the code so that I can programmatically handle transactions

Answer (score 15):

You first have to inject `org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager` - it is an ordinary bean like all the others:

```
@Resource
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```

Now you can use it together with `TransactionTemplate`:

```
final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<String>() {
    @Override
    public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
        transactionManager.rollback(status);
        return ":-(";
    }
});
```

Quite a lot of code, so here is how you should do this:

```
@Transactional
public void onMessage(Message message) {
    //rollback:
    throw new HoustonException("We've got a problem!");
}
```

If you throw a `RuntimeException` from `@Transactional` method, it will automatically rollback that transaction. Otherwise it will be committed.

Note that this doesn't mean that JMS and database is working on the same transaction! When you throw an exception the JMS broker will try to redeliver the message, however chances are that the broker will fail after the DB transaction was committed. If you need to be 100% sure that both JMS and DB updates are atomic, you need distributed transaction manager.

Comment: Will this put the message back on the queue? i.e. the queue will be in transactional scope or not?

Comment: Can I directly use transactionManager without using TransactionTemplate?

Comment: @user1166503: this is a bit more complex (and theoretical) - in default configuration here is what happens: JMS tx start, DB tx start, DB tx commit, JMS tx commit. If something happens between 3rd and 4th step, JMS tx is rolled back but DB is already committed. This is a problem because data is persisted but the message will be put back to the queue. / Yes, you can use `PlatformTransactionManager` directly, but it is a bit inconvienient, template tries to simplify it.

Comment: That helps but still not sure how will the transaction rollback code given by you, be added inside onMessage() method? The method has @Transactional annotations as well as programmatic transaction.

Comment: @user1166503: the first code snippet creates a new DB transaction and rolls it back. The latter will rollback both since the exception escapes `onMessage` (to be precise, you must also add custom [`ErrorHandler`](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?91036) as Spring swallows JMS `onMessage()` exceptions.

Comment: Getting clearer. One more question - Currently I am setting transactionManager property and WebsphereUowTransactionManager in Spring DMLC. Is it ok or needs to be changed? because now it is no longer distributed transaction.

Comment: @user1166503: I am not sure I understand, but transactions are typically bound to thread, so if you are injecting the same JEE tx manager that JMS uses, chances are the transaction is distributed. But please post another question, I am only guessing.

Comment: I was reading this link and trying to relate to this to what you wrote http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-tx-participation

Answer (score 2):

> Spring abstracts underlying transaction manger using `PlatformTransactionManager`.
>   At runtime we can inject platform specific transaction manager shown in the following image.

[image]

We can get *Transaction Manager* reference in spring programmatic approach the following two ways:

1. **Using interface** `PlatformTransactionManager` : We have to explicitly create a `TransactionDefinition` and `TransactionStatus` object.

For Example:

```
       @Resource
       private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
       public void create(String name, Integer age, Integer marks, Integer year){

          TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
          TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

      try {
             //jmsTemplate statements
             transactionManager.commit(status);
          } catch (DataAccessException e) {
             System.out.println("Error in creating record, rolling back");
             transactionManager.rollback(status);
             throw e;
          }
```

2. **Using class** `TransactionTemplate` :

We do not have to explicitly create a `TransactionDefinition` and `TransactionStatus` object. The `TransactionTemplate` provides a callback method called *execute* where we can add our business logic that we want to wrap in a transaction.

There are two types of callback methods that we can use to wrap our code i.e `TransactionCallbackWithoutResult` and `TransactionCallback(T)`

For Example:

```
@Resource
private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;

public void deleteUser(final int uid) {
  transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus paramTransactionStatus) {
    try{
        //statements
    }catch (Exception e) {
      //use this to rollback exception in case of exception
      paramTransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly();
    }
    }
  });

}

public int insertUser(final User user) {
//use TransactionCallback handler if some result is returned
return  transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Integer>() {
  public Integer doInTransaction(TransactionStatus paramTransactionStatus) {
    //statements
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: I use the first approach and I noticed that some exceptions leave the connection in a bad state. So the following requests using that connection from the pool are throwing errors. Is there anything else to do beside rollback?